# Are water electrolysis hydrogen generators likely to damage car engines or make them more efficient?

Tags: electrical, aftermarket-upgrade, mileage, alternative-fuels

I've seen electrolysis using glass jars and baking soda to separate water to make hydrogen and oxygen using the alternator for additional fuel for gasoline engines. Is this likely to cause damage to the engine and if not, how do I make it work on a fuel injection engine? Is it dangerous in any other way?

[image]

Comment: What “stuff” exactly : you should supply sources- have you checked the power input required?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not maintenance or repair.

Comment: @SolarMike where else would I ask this?

Comment: What do you mean by “normal”? Systems can be designed for 12, 24, 48 or 240, 360 480 volts DC - high voltage DC is Very dangerous ... the system I installed has a peak DC voltage of 400 as the inverter is designed for that and high volts low current keeps the losses down (proportional to current squared times resistance).

Comment: Are you asking if a combination of hydrogen and oxygen is dangerous? Because it is super duper dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Note that whatever hydrogen you produce will contain energy from the car battery. The car battery is charged by the alternator, which gives you energy obtained from fuel.

What you describe aims to be a perpetual motion machine but isn't. The inefficiency of the electrolysis (less than 100%) and the inefficiency of the alternator mean your overall scheme actually REDUCES the fuel efficiency of your car, not increasing it.

If you want to have a car run by electricity, consider buying an electric car. Way more energy-efficient than fiddling with hydrogen.

Comment: [This web article](https://autoexpert.com.au/posts/do-car-hydrogen-generators-really-work) tends to agree with you, almost point for point. There is no free meal.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  the fuel spent in cracking water to H and O2 is less than the output. It is not perpetual at all. It is preconditioning water as fuel?

Comment: I like this answer because it addresses energy losses due to conversions. Now consider how energy inefficient electric cars are. Start with burning something to heat water to steam, spinning a turbine, through transformers., across wires, to create chemical potential (charging battery) to electricity  VS  burning gas to make expanding gasses.